# How do I change the x and y axes in subplots using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to use this data: `[1,2,3], [3,4,5]` to plot a vertical bar chart,
horizontal bar chart and a blank plot in one pyplot figure that would look like
the image in this example:

[image]

but my code so far plots slightly differently as seen here. Look at the x-axis on bar chart 1 and y-axis on horizontal bar chart 2. I'm trying to get bar chart 1 x-axis to look like the y-axis on barh. Now the numbers are not in decimals (e.g 1.0,2.0) and there are no numbers shown for 1.5,2.5 and 3.5. (I made some progress thanks to unutbu's explanation):

[another updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osYjR.jpg)

Please see my updated code below, I am totally new to plotting
and still trying to understand how this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

sid = [1, 2, 3]
bel = [3, 4, 5]

y_pos = np.arange(len(sid))+1.5
ax[0].bar(y_pos, bel, align='center', alpha=0.5)
ax[0].set_xticks(y_pos, sid)
ax[0].set_xlim(1.0,4.0)
ax[0].set_ylim(0, 5)

y_pos = np.arange(len(sid)) + 1
ax[1].barh(y_pos, bel, height=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
ax[1].set_yticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
ax[1].set_ylim(1, 4)

sid = []
bel = []
y_pos = np.arange(len(sid))
ax[2].barh(y_pos, bel, align='center', alpha=0.5)
ax[2].set_yticks([0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
ax[2].set_xticks([0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
ax[2].set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two plots you shared? They are exactly same

Comment: @Bazingaa 
I'm sorry, I uploaded the wrong image. Please look at it again

Comment: @unutbu I uploaded the wrong image. Please compare again

Comment: In both the example image and the result the axes appear to be proportionally the same. What width are you trying to change?

Comment: @unutbu The x axis and y axis on each row in the second pic should look like the x-axis and y-axis on each bar chart in the dark blue bar chart in the first pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on the middle axes. You could use

```
y_pos = np.arange(len(sid))+1
plt.barh(y_pos, bel, height=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))
plt.ylim(1, 4)
```

to produce the desired result. Notice that adding 1 to `y_pos` makes `y_pos` equal to 
`array([1, 2, 3])` since adding a constant to a NumPy array adds that constant to each element in the array:

```
In [11]: np.arange(len(sid))
Out[11]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [12]: np.arange(len(sid))+1
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Thus, `plt.barh(y_pos, ..., align='edge')` places the *bottom edge* of the bars at y-locations 1, 2, 3.

---

`np.linspace(1, 4, 7)` generates 7 equally spaced values between 1 and 4:

```
In [13]: np.linspace(1, 4, 7)
Out[13]: array([1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. ])
```

`plt.yticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))` tells matplotlib to label those locations.

---

`plt.ylim(1, 4)` sets the y-limits of the y-axis to range from 1 to 4.

---

On a stylistic note, you might want to consider switching to the ["object-oriented" style of matplotlib programming](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html#a-note-on-the-object-oriented-api-vs-pyplot). Instead of callling `plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)` to activate the second of 3 axes, you could use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
```

to generate the 3 axes. This gives you an object `ax` which is a sequence of 3 axes.

The attraction of coding this way is that you now have a "physical" object to which you can send commands.

Before, when you focus on a single line like

```
plt.barh(y_pos, bel, height=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
```

it was not immediately clear on which axes the bar chart will appear. 
Now, using the object-oriented matplotlib coding style, this command would be

```
ax[1].barh(y_pos, bel, height=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
```

so you would know immediately that the second axes is being drawn upon.

Although it may be a little more verbose (i.e. more typing), as your programs
grow in complexity, I think you'll find the "object-oriented" style produces
clearer, more readable code.

Here is what your code would look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

sid = [1, 2, 3]
bel = [3, 4, 5]

y_pos = np.arange(len(sid)) + 1
ax[0].bar(y_pos, bel, width=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
ax[0].set_xticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))
ax[0].set_ylim(0, 5)

ax[1].barh(y_pos, bel, height=0.9, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
ax[1].set_yticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
ax[1].set_ylim(1, 4)

sid = []
bel = []
y_pos = np.arange(len(sid))
ax[2].barh(y_pos, bel, align='center', alpha=0.5)
ax[2].set_yticks([0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
ax[2].set_xticks([0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
ax[2].set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @unutbu but now the first x-axis has issues. The x-axis for the first barchart should be the same as the y-axis on the second horizontal bar chart. I tried adding 1.5 like this: y_pos = np.arange(len(sid))+1.5 and ax[0].set_xlim(1,4). it worked but I can't see the ticks on 1.5,2.5 and 3.5 like it is shown on the horizontal barchart. It only has ticks at 1,2,3,4. Also, why are the numbers 1-4 not in decimal like y-axis for column 2?

Comment: I updated my question and results for you to see what I mean

Comment: You can get the desired xticks for the first axes by using `ax[0].set_xticks(np.linspace(1, 4, 7))`. I've update the code and image to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much! @unutbu I also added limits for all the columns so the margins fit properly. One question is when i change the color to navy blue, its not the same shade as the other picture but I guess thats based on each system. Thanks a lot for the code explanation, now I have a better understanding than what I learnt in class!

Comment: The `alpha=0.5` changes the resulting color because the navy blue is being blended with the white background. If you want pure navy blue, remove the `alpha=0.5` (since that sets the alpha to the default value, 1.0).

Comment: @ubuntu how do I put the ticks all over like on the opposite axis on each plot?

Comment: Call `ax[0].xaxis.tick_top()` and `ax[0].yaxis.tick_right()`, and similarly for `ax[1]` and `ax[2]`. Or do it in a for-loop:  `for axi in ax.ravel(): axi.xaxis.tick_top(); axi.yaxis.tick_right()`.